# how to create navigation react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, routes, react-navigation

I have an app with carousel screen (when I run app) and map screen
on Map screen I have bottom navbar with 2 tabs: tab1 and tab2. once I click tab1 -> I wanna option title='tab1' on the top navbar. same with tab2.

this is Root Navigator:

```
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#C70066' } }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Carousel" component={CarouselScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={TabNavigator}
      
      />
   </Stack.Navigator>
```

and TabNavigator is this :

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBar={TabBar} >
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Tab1"
    component={Screen1}
    options={{
      tabBarAccessibilityLabel: "Tab1",
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Tab2"
    component={Screen2}
    options={{
      tabBarAccessibilityLabel: "Tab2",
    }}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

It should look like this:[image]

Also I need to style Stack.Navigator and add icons + dropdown; I added the only background color, how to style the rest ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add styling and icons to your tab navigation like this

```js
<Tab.Screen
        name="Tab1"
        component={Screen1}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
              <Image
                source={require("../assets/icons/transaction.png")}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={{
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  tintColor: focused ? '#C70066' : 'gray',
                }}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: focused ? 'red' : 'yellow',
                }}>
                Tab1
              </Text>
            </View>
          ),
        }}
      />
```

Bellow, I will show the code on how I add my custom Tab Navigations, and you can see that I keep my tab navigations separately in a file "tabs.js" in a folder called "navigation" (./app/navigation/tabs)

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  BottomTabBar,
} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

import {Home} from '../screens';
import {COLORS, FONTS, icons} from '../constants';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabBarCustomButtom = ({children, onPress}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{
        top: -30,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        ...styles.shadow,
      }}
      onPress={onPress}>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={[COLORS.primary, COLORS.secondary]}
        style={{width: 70, height: 70, borderRadius: 35}}>
        {children}
      </LinearGradient>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const Tabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        showLabel: false,
        style: {
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
          borderTopColor: 'transparent',
          height: 100,
        },
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
              <Image
                source={icons.home}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={{
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  tintColor: focused ? COLORS.primary : COLORS.black,
                }}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: focused ? COLORS.primary : COLORS.black,
                  ...FONTS.body5,
                }}>
                HOME
              </Text>
            </View>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Portfolio"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
              <Image
                source={icons.pie_chart}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={{
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  tintColor: focused ? COLORS.primary : COLORS.black,
                }}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: focused ? COLORS.primary : COLORS.black,
                  ...FONTS.body5,
                }}>
                PORTFOLIO
              </Text>
            </View>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Transaction"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
              <Image
                source={icons.transaction}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={{
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  tintColor: COLORS.white,
                }}
              />
            </View>
          ),
          tabBarButton: (props) => <TabBarCustomButtom {...props} />,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Prices"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
              <Image
                source={icons.line_graph}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={{
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  tintColor: focused ? COLORS.primary : COLORS.black,
                }}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: focused ? COLORS.primary : COLORS.black,
                  ...FONTS.body5,
                }}>
                PRICES
              </Text>
            </View>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
              <Image
                source={icons.settings}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={{
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  tintColor: focused ? COLORS.primary : COLORS.black,
                }}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: focused ? COLORS.primary : COLORS.black,
                  ...FONTS.body5,
                }}>
                SETTINGS
              </Text>
            </View>
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  shadow: {
    shadowColor: COLORS.primary,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 10,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,

    elevation: 5,
  },
});

export default Tabs;
```

this is Root Navigator:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

import Tabs from './app/navigation/tabs';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
        initialRouteName={'Home'}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Tabs} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```